# Ember - How to get an id?

Tags: ember.js, model

I'm trying to save a model and get its id in order to add it to another model.

**Model 1.save > get its ID**

```
var something_else = this.get('randomised');
Model 2.
var hash = {
something : something_else
**model_1_id : ????**
}
model2.creatrecord('model2', hash).save();
```

I've tried all kinds of solutions.  The best by far was

```
model2.creatrecord('model2', hash).get('id);
```

But that's definitely not the right way.
For making myself clearer I've added JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/etemONe/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Ember Record documentation:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/

> IDs are usually assigned by the server when you save them for the
>   first time, but you can also generate IDs client-side.

Since you're using the fixture adapter, you'll need to generate the id on the client side, and save it back to the server. This could be bad in the long run though, so you might want to look into a different adapter that will let the server handle it.

From Kingpin2k:
Save returns a promise, and that promise resolves as the record, at that point you'll have an id.  Additionally createRecord returns the record, and you could have just kept a reference to that, then printed it out after the save completes.

in your code,

```
this.savePerson(hash).then(function(record){
  console.log(record.get('id'));
  self.saveAgentAssociation(agentAddress)
});
```

http://jsbin.com/isoYayA/4/edit

Comment: Fixtureadapter is just for testing, later it will be DjangoRESTAdapter.

Comment: Btw is that the solution u would use with other adapters as well right ?

Comment: Yes, after your save it's common practice for the id to be returned and then accessible after the promise is resolved from the save.  It's a little less common practice to call another method which returns the promise instead of the record.  Aka, it'd be more common practice to have that method create the record, and return the record, then you save etc, but that's up to you.

Comment: This is what i came up with - https://gist.github.com/kristjanreinhold/c30a7f271df6d435216c . Anyway do u happen to know any tutorial , example of how to do model-> has many     For instance there is a person that works in 2 organization - First i need to multiple fields with dynamic id  and then how does the ember part look like ? Sorry if bothering, thanks for previous answer .

Comment: oh whoa. Well, do you want to answer with your text?  I can delete mine so that you get the accepted answer.